The difference between accepting multiple parameters and accepting a single object
I write a library that deals with an API and I am considering two interface options:
1. api_client.init_payment(order_id=..., price=..., ...)
2. api_client.init_payment(InitPaymentRequest(order_id=..., price=..., ...))
Generally, I don't see a big difference between them. I only prefer the [1] since it is more minimalistic and easy to use. But I'll have to create the InitPaymentRequest object internally anyway, so I just was thinking maybe [2] also makes sense... But is it justified?
Which option is generally better?

The name of the refactoring is Introduce Parameter Object.

I decided it is inconvenient for clients when they are forced to create a request object. Especially when an API method accepts only one parameter.
So I think the [1] is better. The only drawback is that I still have to create a request object under the hood and if a new API parameter gets introduced, I'll have to add it in two places (the APIClient method and the Request class). But it is not a big deal.

Both options are valid. However, in terms of clean code - too many input parameters for a function considered as a "bad smell". Robert C. Martin even dedicates a section for this in his book Clean Code, and recommends that when you start to add more and more input parameters to your function - you should consider wrapping them in a class. I find this article as a good summary of the book's section.

I know it, but I don't think it is the case. There will anyway be many input parameters because the API accepts a lot of parameters. Just with the second option, they will be defined in the init (which is also a function).
